# Solana: calculate PDA in Java/Kotlin

Tags: solana

I need to calculate PDA ([Program Derived Address](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#program-derived-addresses)) using Java/Kotlin open-source libraries.

In Solana [Web3 Javascript](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/f8c2d21686e0afb0718fb4ab3abe72b2bfd34c1c/src/publickey.ts#L189) library there is an algorithm, which internally uses Tweetnacl-JS.

Unfortunately, my knowledge of cryptography is not enough to port this to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an awesome `Solana.kt` library that has [PDA calculation](https://github.com/ajamaica/Solana.kt/blob/cf1d8c6884f54779ac96995330662e59569644a1/solana/src/main/java/com/solana/core/PublicKey.kt#L80)

Comment: Hey Sergei, does Solana.lt works well for you?